# bs-dropdown is not closing automatically on next rightClick in ui-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid in my project. My requirement is on right click in the rows of grid a bs-dropdown has to generate. I am achieved this by using  data-trigger="contextmenu" event. The issue is the drop down is overlapping with previous row dropdown. Any idea to fix this issue. screenshot attached here.

[contextmenu overlapping screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ1td.png)

Here am attaching another screenshot of the issue. the first dropdown is not closing on next row right click. Not able to create plunkr to share the code.

[bs-dropdown not closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ8SW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it is not necessarily an angularjs issue, but some css. I would use a  dynamic z-index, e.g. using the current timestamp as the `z-index` CSS property in a script tag.

Comment: yes, but i am unable to make it. can you please give some example.

Comment: Share your code in a plunker, and then i will try to amend it, ok?

Comment: can you seen my second screenshot? still you believe its css issue? please advice.